# Laravel 5 form request validation returning forbidden error

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am trying to use Laravel 5.1's form request validation, to authorize if the request is from the owner. The validation is used when the user is trying to update part of the table `clinics` through the `show.blade.php`.

My set up so far:

**routes.php:**

```
Route::post('clinic/{id}', 
    array('as' => 'postUpdateAddress', 'uses' => 'ClinicController@postUpdateAddress'));
```

**ClinicController.php:**

```
public function postUpdateAddress($id, 
        \App\Http\Requests\UpdateClinicAddressFormRequest $request)
    {
        $clinic             = Clinic::find($id);
        $clinic->save();

        return Redirect::route('clinic.index');
    }
```

**UpdateClinicAddressFormRequest.php:**

```
public function authorize()

    {
        $clinicId = $this->route('postUpdateAddress');

        return Clinic::where('id', $clinicId)
        ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->exists();
    }
```

**Show.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => array('postUpdateAddress', $clinic->id), 'role'=>'form')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

> If I `dd($clinicId)` within the authorize function, it returns `null`, so I think that's where the problem lies!

Any help why on submit it's saying 'forbidden' would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are getting **Forbidden Error** because `authorize()` method of form request is returning **false**:

The issue is this: `$clinicId = $this->route('postUpdateAddress');`

To access a route parameter value in Form Requests you could do this:

`$clinicId = \Route::input('id'); //to get the value of {id}`

so `authorize()` should look like this:

```
public function authorize()
{
    $clinicId = \Route::input('id'); //or $this->route('id');

    return Clinic::where('id', $clinicId)
    ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->exists();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Something so simple.

Answer (score 4):

I add this owner confirmation to authorize() method in Request and work

```
public function authorize()
{
    return \Auth::check();
}
```